# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'hidden_layer' (type GRU)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to implement this https://github.com/roemmele/keras-rnn-notebooks (Pos tagging example using tensorflow)

The problem is that: After constructing the model, shape of tensor is not matching so I got in trouble.

I think it is not working well in the latest tensorflow version.
In tensorflow version 2.3, it works well. But by using tensorflow version 2.13, it is not working.

I want to use latest version to help begginers who don't know how to install specific version of tensorflow in my school.

The specific code that I'm having a hard time with is as follows:

I construct the model like this.

```
'''Create the model'''

from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate, TimeDistributed, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, GRU

def create_model(seq_input_len, n_word_input_nodes, n_tag_input_nodes, n_word_embedding_nodes,
                 n_tag_embedding_nodes, n_hidden_nodes, stateful=False, batch_size=32,reset_after=True):
    
    #Layers 1
    word_input = Input(shape=(None,), batch_size=batch_size, name='word_input_layer')
    tag_input = Input(shape=(None,), batch_size=batch_size, name='tag_input_layer')

    #Layers 2
    word_embeddings = Embedding(input_dim=n_word_input_nodes,
                                output_dim=n_word_embedding_nodes, 
                                mask_zero=True, name='word_embedding_layer')(word_input) #mask_zero will ignore 0 padding
    #Output shape = (batch_size, seq_input_len, n_word_embedding_nodes)
    tag_embeddings = Embedding(input_dim=n_tag_input_nodes,
                               output_dim=n_tag_embedding_nodes,
                               mask_zero=True, name='tag_embedding_layer')(tag_input) 
    #Output shape = (batch_size, seq_input_len, n_tag_embedding_nodes)
    
    #Layer 3
    merged_embeddings = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_embedding_layer')([word_embeddings, tag_embeddings])
    #Output shape =  (batch_size, seq_input_len, n_word_embedding_nodes + n_tag_embedding_nodes)
    
    #Layer 4
    hidden_layer = GRU(units=n_hidden_nodes, return_sequences=True,
                       reset_after=reset_after,
                       stateful=stateful, name='hidden_layer')(merged_embeddings)
    #Output shape = (batch_size, seq_input_len, n_hidden_nodes)
    
    #Layer 5
    output_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(units=n_tag_input_nodes, 
                                         activation='softmax'), name='output_layer')(hidden_layer)
    # Output shape = (batch_size, seq_input_len, n_tag_input_nodes)
    
    #Specify which layers are input and output, compile model with loss and optimization functions
    model = Model(inputs=[word_input, tag_input], outputs=output_layer)
    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                  optimizer='adam')
    
    return model
```

And error happens in the following codes

```
'''Predict tags for sentences in test set'''

import numpy

pred_tags = []
for _, sent in test_sents.iterrows():
    tok_sent = sent['Tokenized_Sentence']
    sent_idxs = sent['Sentence_Idxs']
    sent_gold_tags = sent['Tagged_Sentence']
    sent_pred_tags = []
    prev_tag = 0  #initialize predicted tag sequence with padding
    for cur_word in sent_idxs:
        # cur_word and prev_tag are just integers, but the model expects an input array
        # with the shape (batch_size, seq_input_len), so prepend two dimensions to these values
        p_next_tag = predictor_model.predict(x=[numpy.array(cur_word)[None, None],
                                                numpy.array(prev_tag)[None, None]])[0]
        prev_tag = numpy.argmax(p_next_tag, axis=-1)[0]
        sent_pred_tags.append(prev_tag)
    predictor_model.reset_states()

    #Map tags back to string labels
    sent_pred_tags = [tags_lexicon_lookup[tag] for tag in sent_pred_tags]
    pred_tags.append(sent_pred_tags) #filter padding 

test_sents['Predicted_Tagged_Sentence'] = pred_tags

#print sample
for _, sent in test_sents[:10].iterrows():
    print("SENTENCE:\t{}".format("\t".join(sent['Tokenized_Sentence'])))
    print("PREDICTED:\t{}".format("\t".join(sent['Predicted_Tagged_Sentence'])))
    print("GOLD:\t\t{}".format("\t".join(sent['Tagged_Sentence'])), "\n\n")
```

When I go through `predictor_model.predict`, the following error occurs as shown in the images.

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'hidden_layer' (type GRU).
    
    Input tensor `model_20/hidden_layer/ReadVariableOp:0` enters the loop with shape (1, 500), but has shape (None, 500) after one iteration. To allow the shape to vary across iterations, use the `shape_invariants` argument of tf.while_loop to specify a less-specific shape.
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'hidden_layer' (type GRU):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1, 400), dtype=float32)
      • mask=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=bool)
      • training=False
      • initial_state=None
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGofC.png)

[ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'hidden_layer' (type GRU)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Auj4.png)

Why am I getting the error and how can I solve it?

Is there any possible solution except installing the old version of tensorflow?

I treid to replace `x=[numpy.array(cur_word)[None, None],numpy.array(prev_tag)[None, None]])[0]` with `x=numpy.expand_dims([numpy.array(cur_word)[None, None],numpy.array(prev_tag)[None, None]], axis=1))[0]` in the `p_next_tag` but it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your question with the full error trace as *text*, *not* as image - see how to create a [mre].